# Node JS Postgresql query returning data as JSON

Tags: html, node.js, json, postgresql

I have a Node js web page, working with a Postgresql data base. When I do queries to db, result.rows return the data as JSON (as pg.Result says: 'By default node-postgres creates a map from the name to value of each column, giving you a json-like object back for each row.'). I used Fetch API for this.

I want to return the data as I saved it in db, just text (in fact, it's a very large string with html tags, for paragraphs and words styles).

This is my code:

```
router.get('/capitulos/:id', (req, res) => {

var cap = req.params.id;

try{

    const { Client } = require('pg');

    const connection = {
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    }

    const client = new Client(connection);

    client.connect();

    const queryString = 'SELECT txtcaps FROM blazecaps WHERE numcaps = $1';

    client.query(queryString, [cap])
    .then(response => res.send(response.rows))
    .then(e => console.log(e));
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}});

//Fetch API in HTML page:
        fetch('/capitulos/' + num, {
            method: 'get'
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            document.getElementById('capis').innerHTML = text;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error : ' + error);
        });
```

This is how looks like the query output:
[Blaze web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnvq1.jpg)

Beforehand, thank you very much!

Comment: I managed to remove the characters of string with this: var chapter = text.replace(/\\n/g,'').replace('[{"txtcaps":"', '').replace('"}]', '');